# use code init UITextView, Constraints not working

Tags: autolayout, constraints

use code init UITextView, Constraints retuen the NSArray count is 0

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
NSLog(@"constraints:%@",textView.constraints);}

2016-08-08 17:43:32.347 demo[5756:2552780] constraints:()
```

but use storyboard init is ok.

Comment: don't mind, just for checking, have you connected the delegate for the textview?

Comment: `textViewDidChange:` the method has been called, just `constraints` NSAarray count is 0.

Comment: Question is not clear. Give more details